# How to separate fasta string into multiple rows keeing the number of columns unchanged in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, bioinformatics, fasta

I am trying to read a fasta file and display the sequence as separate amino acids as a data frame.
1 seq = 1 column

This is what I've got so far:

**FASTA_test.txt** contains:

```
>sp|Q9UER7|DAXX_HUMAN Death domain-associated protein 6 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=DAXX PE=1 SV=2
MATANSIIVLDDDDEDEAAAQPGPSHPLPNAASPGAEAPSSSEPHGARGSSSSGGKKCYK
LENEKLFEEFLELCKMQTADHPEVVPFLYNRQQRAHSLFLASAEFCNILSRVLSRARSRP
AKLYVYINELCTVLKAHSAKKKLNLAPAATTSNEPSGNNPPTHLSLDPTNAENTASQSPR
TRGSRRQIQRLEQLLALYVAEIRRLQEKELDLSELDDPDSAYLQEARLKRKLIRLFGRLC
ELKDCSSLTGRVIEQRIPYRGTRYPEVNRRIERLINKPGPDTFPDYGDVLRAVEKAAARH
SLGLPRQQLQLMAQDAFRDVGIRLQERRHLDLIYNFGCHLTDDYRPGVDPALSDPVLARR
LRENRSLAMSRLDEVISKYAMLQDKSEEGERKKRRARLQGTSSHSADTPEASLDSGEGPS
GMASQGCPSASRAETDDEDDEESDEEEEEEEEEEEEEATDSEEEEDLEQMQEGQEDDEEE
DEEEEAAAGKDGDKSPMSSLQISNEKNLEPGKQISRSSGEQQNKGRIVSPSLLSEEPLAP
SSIDAESNGEQPEELTLEEESPVSQLFELEIEALPLDTPSSVETDISSSRKQSEEPFTTV
LENGAGMVSSTSFNGGVSPHNWGDSGPPCKKSRKEKKQTGSGPLGNSYVERQRSVHEKNG
KKICTLPSPPSPLASLAPVADSSTRVDSPSHGLVTSSLCIPSPARLSQTPHSQPPRPGTC
KTSVATQCDPEEIIVLSDSD
>sp|P29590|PML_HUMAN Protein PML OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PML PE=1 SV=3
MEPAPARSPRPQQDPARPQEPTMPPPETPSEGRQPSPSPSPTERAPASEEEFQFLRCQQC
QAEAKCPKLLPCLHTLCSGCLEASGMQCPICQAPWPLGADTPALDNVFFESLQRRLSVYR
QIVDAQAVCTRCKESADFWCFECEQLLCAKCFEAHQWFLKHEARPLAELRNQSVREFLDG
TRKTNNIFCSNPNHRTPTLTSIYCRGCSKPLCCSCALLDSSHSELKCDISAEIQQRQEEL
DAMTQALQEQDSAFGAVHAQMHAAVGQLGRARAETEELIRERVRQVVAHVRAQERELLEA
VDARYQRDYEEMASRLGRLDAVLQRIRTGSALVQRMKCYASDQEVLDMHGFLRQALCRLR
QEEPQSLQAAVRTDGFDEFKVRLQDLSSCITQGKDAAVSKKASPEAASTPRDPIDVDLPE
EAERVKAQVQALGLAEAQPMAVVQSVPGAHPVPVYAFSIKGPSYGEDVSNTTTAQKRKCS
QTQCPRKVIKMESEEGKEARLARSSPEQPRPSTSKAVSPPHLDGPPSPRSPVIGSEVFLP
NSNHVASGAGEAEERVVVISSSEDSDAENSSSRELDDSSSESSDLQLEGPSTLRVLDENL
ADPQAEDRPLVFFDLKIDNETQKISQLAAVNRESKFRVVIQPEAFFSIYSKAVSLEVGLQ
HFLSFLSSMRRPILACYKLWGPGLPNFFRALEDINRLWEFQEAISGFLAALPLIRERVPG
ASSFKLKNLAQTYLARNMSERSAMAAVLAMRDLCRLLEVSPGPQLAQHVYPFSSLQCFAS
LQPLVQAAVLPRAEARLLALHNVSFMELLSAHRRDRQGGLKKYSRYLSLQTTTLPPAQPA
FNLQALGTYFEGLLEGPALARAEGVSTPLAGRGLAERASQQS
```

And my codes:

```
library("Biostrings")
fastaFile <- readAAStringSet("~/Desktop/FASTA_test.txt")
seq_name = names(fastaFile)
sequence = paste(fastaFile)
df <- data.frame(seq_name, sequence)
view(df)

#separate the aa into separate columns
df_splited_1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  do.call(expand.grid, strsplit(df$sequence, ""))
})))

view(df_splited_1)
```

The problem I am facing is that the script above separates the amino acids but it puts them in a single column instead of keeping the columns separately.

```
dput(fastaFile)
new("AAStringSet", pool = new("SharedRaw_Pool", xp_list = list(
    <pointer: 0x0>), .link_to_cached_object_list = list(<environment>)), 
    ranges = new("GroupedIRanges", group = c(1L, 1L), start = c(1L, 
    741L), width = c(740L, 882L), NAMES = c("sp|Q9UER7|DAXX_HUMAN Death domain-associated protein 6 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=DAXX PE=1 SV=2", 
    "sp|P29590|PML_HUMAN Protein PML OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PML PE=1 SV=3"
    ), elementType = "ANY", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()), 
    elementType = "AAString", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list())
```

I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: Are you trying to split sequence one character per column? meaning for sequnce 1, you will have 740 columns? `nchar(df$sequence[1]) # [1] 740` If yes, length of second sequence, is longer `nchar(df$sequence[2]) # [1] 882`, how do you want to rowbind them, shorter one will get NAs?

Comment: I wanted to split a sequence one character per row. But I want to keep sequence no.1 in column 1, sequence no.2 in column2, instead of all in one column

Comment: OK, same question, length is different, how do you want to column bind them?

Comment: Oh you're right. I shouldn't use cbind function. I don't want to bind them. Just separate the characters and keep them separately. The sequences are completely unrelated to each other. After separation of the characters, I want to apply a scale and the sequences will be treated separately. I am sorry for confusion.

Comment: Then it is as simple as `strsplit(df$sequence, "")` ?

Comment: I've tried that but I get this error: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 740, 882

Comment: `strsplit(df$sequence, "")` works fine for me.

Comment: Your `dput` gives me an error. `Error: unexpected '<' in:
"new("AAStringSet", pool = new("SharedRaw_Pool", xp_list = list(
    <"` Do I need special library to read this? I already loaded `Biostrings`.

Comment: Biostrings should be fine. I loaded also the following libraries: pacman::p_load(tidyverse, skimr, reader, readr, seqinr, tidyr, gtools, magrittr, dplyr, Biostrings)    But readAAStringSet() is from Biostrings

Comment: @RonakShah dput wouldn't work in this case, it is just pointers to data on the OPs machine. Better just read from text file as `fastaFile <-readAAStringSet("path/to/file/FASTA_test.txt")`